# Question about docker run command parameters, -t -i

Tags: docker

I am confused about these three commands, I don't know the difference among them. Sorry, I am new to docker.

I can not see the difference from the result.Could anybody tell me the difference?

1. docker run -it IMAGE_NAME  /bin/bash
2. docker run -i IMAGE_NAME /bin/bash
3. docker run -i IMAGE_NAME

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docker documentation

> -t              : Allocate a pseudo-tty
>
> -i              : Keep STDIN open even if not attached

For interactive processes (like a shell), you must use -i -t together in order to allocate a tty for the container process.

docker run -i imagename /bin/bash

This will attach a shell to the container. You can run any shell command on the shell.

docker run -i imagename

This will dump the stdout on the terminal. Similar to docker run  but with ability to take input from pipe.

Answer (score 1):

Docker `run` command has some parameters to run command in **Detached**  or **Foreground** mode.

-i and -t falls under Foreground mode.

```
-i    : Keep STDIN open even if not attached
-t    : Allocate a pseudo-tty
```

In case of -i whenever you run docker container command passed to it will be fired. in your case  "`/bin/bash`"

**Note from Doc**

> For interactive processes (like a shell), you must use -i -t together
>   in order to allocate a tty for the container process. -i -t is often
>   written -it as you’ll see in later examples. Specifying -t is
>   forbidden when the client is receiving its standard input from a pipe,
>   as in:

More Detail [Here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/)

Answer (score 0):

docker run -it IMAGE_NAME /bin/bash --> you will be able to enter into container if you use -i(interactive) option (which is for executing any commands in the container) and -t(tty) which gives you the terminal to enter any command, /bin/bash is the type of linux shell (eg. sh,ksh,bash etc.)